# How do I get the StatusID of a duplicate Tweet?

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-rest-api

We're POSTing a Status to Twitter via the REST API using LINQ To Twitter.

When the Status is successfully POSTed we get a StatusID in the response which we use to Retweet the Status later.

If we have already successfully POSTed the Status then we get an error response saying that it's a duplicate.

This duplicate detection is fantastic and helps us avoid spamming, but the error response doesn't appear to contain the StatusID of the original Status.

This presents us with a problem as we can't Retweet the original Status as we don't have it's StatusID.

I had a look with Fiddler, and I couldn't see the StatusID hidden away in the body or the header.

I've had a look at the documentation for [POSTing a status](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update) and I can't see any extra parameters for requesting the StatusID to be returned.

Is the only option to grab the users Status stream and work our way backwards until we find a Status with matching content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twitter Community](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-do-i-get-the-statusid-of-a-duplicate-tweet/60137)

> Unfortunately if you post a duplicate status there only an error code, no response body that could carry the ID of the original, so I don't see any other easy way to do this!